# Hopalong fractals, checking c synatx

Tags: c, fractals

I have written following code in order to produce simple list of double pairs to import in plot program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>


int main(void)
{
int i;
double x=2,y=3;
for(i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
    x = y- x/fabs(x)*sqrt(fabs(x+0.7));
    y = 0.3-x;
    printf("%5.4f , %5.4f\n" ,x,y);
    }
return 0;
}
```

I don't get what I expect from this functions. Instead of hopalong fractal I get linear progression graph. Is this only syntax error?

Comment: It's unclear what is wrong here. What output are you getting and what are you expecting? I have no idea what a hopalong fractal is. Could it be that you are missing some parentheses on the line where `x` is assigned?

Comment: I have compiled and executed the program. But I dont know why my results are not giving the desired graphs?

Comment: Probably because you're doing the wrong calculation but we don't know what the right one is, so it's impossible to say.

Answer (score 1):

When you assign `y`, you use the new value of `x`, which has just been updated. The calculation requires the `x` value from the last step. Make a copy and use that:

```
int main(void)
{
    double x = 2;
    double y = 3;
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        double xx = x;

        x = y - x/fabs(x)*sqrt(fabs(x + 0.7));
        y = 0.3 - xx;

        printf("%5.4f , %5.4f\n" ,x,y);
    }
    return 0;
}
```